How can I mount a metal planter box around my window over vinyl siding?
I want to install a metal plant box on my window. The metal would probably be just like fence railings sold on Home Depot or Lowes (not wrought nor aluminum). Something like the pictures below (for reference only). The house has vinyl siding and wood window frame. It's not for human, but I want it to be able to hold maybe 200-250 lbs weight (including the plant box). A big AC window unit is probably about 80lbs(?). Looking for advice on what is the best way of securing it.  I'm thinking:

Make the plant box the size of window frame and screw everything to the frame.
Make the plant box larger, screw the bottom part to bottom of window frame. Both sides to the vinyl siding (with toggle screws).
Either case above add triangular brackets (on vinyl siding) for supports

Let me know your thoughts, especially if you've done similar project in the past, or if there is anything can be improved. Thanks.



If the metal frame or crews corrode at all, expect unsightly rust/corrosion stains on the vinyl siding.

Stack Exchange policies require that images which are not the creative work of the poster be properly attributed via a link to where the image was found. Please update your posting to bring this into compliance.

The screws will be galvanized and the metal will be sprayed with protective enamel. Image source: https://www.etsy.com/listing/1759205231/metal-wrought-iron-wall-mounted-window, https://www.pinterest.com/pin/847591592388383131/,


A window AC is designed to hold itself in the window opening, with the window sash coming down on top of the AC to jam it in place. (along with screws & L brackets to keep the sash from moving). The AC should be put in place such that is it self-supported by the window, without a shelf underneath it. If your window does not have sashes, look for an AC that is designed to fit self-supported in the existing window.

Window ACs need to be at a slight tilt down on the back, so the water that condenses when the AC runs will ooze out the back of the AC to the outside ground. Any shelf or outside support has to account for this required tilt.

The metal these window boxes are made out of may be weak aluminum tubes. If the manufacturer of the box does not say "supports X pounds", don't expect it to do so.

Anything expected to hold weight outside the house (or inside, for that matter) should attach to the structural members of the house (studs, beams, etc) not frames or surface treatments. Screw into the bones of the wall, not the window frame or siding, for heavy window boxes. You may need to rig up some supports under the siding to allow the box to screw down firmly so the empty spaces of the siding profile do not hold the box floating flexibly on the wall.


I would recommend not supporting the AC with the window box. Mount the AC so no window box is needed, then mount the window box decoratively around the window and AC such that the AC does not touch the window box.

The plan is to push out the unit when it's not used (i.e. winter time), and cover it up with a tarp. This way, I can close the window and lose heat. About tilting it, I think I can just add a piece of wood near the front, between window frame and under the AC unit.
